# How to read multiple textboxes and insert into database?

Tags: razor

How can I update multiple textbox in database using ASP.NET Web Pages(razor syntax). I want to edit emails of students. And the number of rows containing textbox varies or dynamic. Somebody help.

```
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Jason</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtbox1"></td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
    <td>Kripkee</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtbox2"></td>
    </tr>

          <tr>
    <td>Kane</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtbox3"></td>
    </tr>

          <tr>
    <td>Michael</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtbox4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>    
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Assuming you have a view model providing a list of students.

View -

```
@foreach (var student in Model.Students)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@student.Name</td>
                            <td><input name="studentEmails[@student.Id]"/></td>
                        </tr>                    
                    }
```

Controller -

```
public ActionResult UpdateEmails(IDictionary<int, string> studentEmails)
```